# Chapter X, Section 2, Proposition 1 of Stein's harmonic analysis

Tags: harmonic-analysis

The Proposition claims:

Suppose we are given a countable collection $\{d\mu_j\}$ of finite nennegative measure on $\mathbb R^n$, supported in a fixed compact set. Define the maximal operator

$$ Mf(x)=\sup_j |(f*d\mu_j)(x)|. $$

Suppose $p$ is given, with $1\le p<\infty$. Assume that for each $f\in L^p$ we have $Mf<\infty$ on a set of positive measure. Then $M$ is of weak-type $(p,p)$.

The proof uses an "infinite monkey lemma": Let $\{E_j\}$ be a collection of subsets of a fixed compact set with $\sum_j |E_j|=\infty$. Then there is a sequence of translations $F_j=E_j+x_j$ such that $\limsup_j F_j=\mathbb R^n$.

Then the proof shows the weak-type inequality for functions supported in the unit cube $Q$, so that $Mf$ is supported in another compact set $B$. Assume the contrary. Then we can find, for each $k$, a positive number $\alpha_k$ and a $g_k\in L^p$ supported in the unit cube such that

$$ |B\cap \{Mf>\alpha_k\}|\ge\frac{2^k}{\alpha_k}^p\|g_k\|_{L^p}^p.$$

Now replace $g_k$ by $g_k'=kg_k/\alpha_k$. Then we have a sequence $g_k'\in L^p$ with

$$ \frac{|B\cap \{Mg_k'>k\}|}{\|g_k'\|_{L^p}^p}\to\infty $$

as $k\to\infty$. Then the proof claims that "taking subsequences of the $g_k'$ (with possible repetitions) allows us to find a sequence $f_k\in L^p$ and a sequence of constants $R_k\to\infty$ so that, taking

$$ E_k=B\cap\{Mf_k>R_k\}, $$

we have $\sum_k |E_k|=\infty$, while $\sum_k \|f_k\|_{L^p}^p<\infty$.

My doubt lies in the choice of $f_k$. For example, if $g_k'$ satisfies $\|g_k'\|_{L^p}=k$. Then there is no way to adjust the magnitudes of $g_k'$ again so that $\sum_k \|g_k'\|_{L^p}^p<\infty$ while $R_k\to\infty$. In the special case of maximal functions with respect to rectangles, one can use the dilations to adjust the $L^p$ norms, but in the general situation as in the Proposition above, is there a similar adjustment so that $\sum_k \|g_k'\|_{L^p}^p<\infty$?

Comment: Since $|B\cap \{Mg_k'>k\}|\le |B|$, then necessarily $\lVert g_k'\rVert_p\to 0$.

Comment: Oh my! That's much easier than I have expected.